# Render a component in specific part of the Page in Angularjs2

Tags: angular

I have a series of components like 
"HeaderComponent", 
"FooterComponent",
"LeftNavComponent",
"MenuComponent".

How do i insert / render these components to the required sections of the page for example, headercomponent has to be rendered in the head part of the page and footercomponent has to be rendered in bottom of the page.

Can somebody enlighten me on this.

Regards

Comment: are you using bootstrap ?

Comment: Why don't you just add the components tag `<my-component></my-component>` where you want to add a component?

Comment: hey Thanks Gunter, I forgot that we can insert using the component selector in the specifc divs of the page.